# Web Api Project Works Fine on Visual Studio But Not Rider

Tags: rider

So I wanted to try out Rider. I tried to run my startup project through Rider but I seem to be getting the following error when I open up the url in the browser:

```
 Could not load file or assembly 'AMLP' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'AMLP' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'AMLP' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Stack Trace:


[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'AMLP' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +37
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +159
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +80
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +29
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +39

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'AMLP' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +777
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +229
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +140
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +176
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +99
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +310
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +165
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +590

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'AMLP' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10087352
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +99
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +263
```

When I open the project using Visual Studio and run it, it works fine, looking up the same URL yields no issue. So not sure exactly what I need to do to rectify this issue.

So far I tried copying the applicationhost.config from my **.vs** folder and used that to build the applicationhost.config for Rider but didn't work. Setting the MSBuild.exe from Rider's to Visual Studio's version also didn't work.

Here's an image of what the error looks like if that helps:

[image]

Comment: `applicationhost.config` is an IIS concept, so you either configure Rider to use IIS or switch over to IIS Express.

Comment: Is it? Because when I run my project I noticed it runs it with the following arguments: `"D:\Program Files\JetBrains\JetBrains Rider 2022.2.3\plugins\dpa\DotFiles\JetBrains.DPA.Runner.exe" --handle=1992 --backend-pid=14456 --detach-event-name=dpa.detach.1992 "C:/Program Files (x86)/IIS Express/iisexpress.exe" /config:D:/Application/MyProject/.idea/config/applicationhost.config /site:AMLP /apppool:Clr4IntegratedAppPool`. It seems to be using the applicationhost.config. Or is this something completely unrelated to the issue that I am having right now?

Comment: You're of course right  both IIS and IIS Express do use `applicationhost.config`. What I mean is that the **direct** usage of `applicationhost.config` is usually not necessary when working with IIS Express - one can configure it either via `*.csproj`  or `Web.config`. Therefore I still think that you're on the right track and have to configure your project to use IIS Express or configure Rider to use IIS.

Comment: How was your assemblies compiled? Note that Rider launches the 32 bit IIS Express, which won't work for 64 bit assemblies and is usually the cause of such exceptions.

Comment: @LexLi yes they are compiled for 64-bit. How do I set Rider to launch the 64-bit version of IIS Express? I assumed that Rider did this by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception indicates that the IIS Express bitness does not match the bitness of your assemblies.

To change IIS Express bitness in Rider, you need to follow [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-6608)

[image]

Comment: Feel really stupid that I overlooked this haha. Thanks alot. I changed the **Exe Path** from `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress,.exe` to `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress,.exe` and that fixed the issue